# Why JS lables does'nt work when not used with loops

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I wrote a small JS Code here. Which runs without any errors

```js
repeat:
  while(true){
    console.log('Start');
    break repeat;
    console.log('End');
  }
```

But when i don't use the while statement the program throws an error  `Undefined label repeat`

```js
repeat:
    console.log('Start');
    break repeat;
    console.log('End');
```

Why the program throws that error? Are labels only made for loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, it works with code [blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). And while you do not have any block to break, the code throws an error.

```js
repeat: {
    console.log('Start');
    break repeat;
    console.log('End');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, "such a construct is basically a `goto` in drag."  I would prefer to see the logic written with a `continue` statement, like this:

```
while (true) {
  console.log('start');
  if (x == y) continue;
  console.log('foo');
  if (q != z) continue;
  ...
}
```

My point being that "it's still a `while` loop, just as I said it would be," except that it doesn't always reach the end.  When it *doesn't* reach the end, it always goes back to the top.

The `break` statement is most common in the case of `while (true)` and is, in fact, expected by anyone else who reads your code.  The logic runs until some condition is met, at which point it "breaks out of the loop" and goes to the statement following it.

When you "`break` like a `goto`," your logic becomes much more difficult to puzzle-out and to understand.  This is a very important consideration.  "Write simply and clearly, and in the way that is customarily expected.  Don't throw a curve-ball."

Comment: I just asked 
Why the program throws that error? Are labels only made for loops?